# Full manual legend with shape, linetype, labels defined in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, legend

I have have constructed a plot with monthly temperature data with following command. Here I need to add a legend with defined shape(16, 17, 18...), linetype(1,1,2,....), and labels (1977, 1978, 1979....). I tried different ways, but no luck thought did not result any error.

here a section of my data

```
 structure(list(month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", 
"Dec"), class = "factor"), X1977 = c(10.3, 11.8, 15.4, 18.7, 
20.3, 22, 23.5, 24.5, 20.1, 17.2, 15.2, 16.5), X1978 = c(10.3, 
8, 10.8, 16.9, 20.2, 20.3, 20, 20, 17.9, 16.4, 11.4, 12.9), X1979 = c(13.9, 
12, 13.4, 17.5, 19.6, 20.3, 19.3, 19.3, 18.3, 16.1, 14.5, 10.6
)), .Names = c("month", "X1977", "X1978", "X1979"), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))


    p <- ggplot(t.df, aes(month, X1977)) 
    p
    p <-p + geom_point(aes(month, X1977),shape=16) + geom_line(aes(x=1:12, y= X1977))
    p <- p+ geom_point(aes(month, X1978),shape=17) + geom_line(aes(x=1:12, y= X1978))
    p <- p+ geom_point(aes(month, X1979),shape=18) + geom_line(aes(x=1:12, y= X1979), linetype=2)
    p2 <- p+ labs(x="Month", y="Mean Temperature")
    p2

    p2 + theme(legend.position = "right")+
         scale_fill_manual(labels=c("1977", "1978", "1979"))+
         scale_linetype_manual(1,1,2)+ scale_shape_manual(16,17,19)
     # this code does not yield error but legend is not added on the plot
```

Comment: could you share a small sample reproducible data?

Comment: scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,17,19)) the right way to call? similarily for linetype_manual()

Comment: Hi, I added a section of my data in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is your data appears to be in wide format (your time series are in separate columns).  `ggplot2` works best with the long format, where your data is in a key-value pair.  You can transform your data using the `tidyr` package, specifically using the functions `gather` and `spread`.

The second issue is that if you want the `shape`, `fill` and `linetype` to appear in legends, you need to include them within your `aes()` call.  In your code you have no `fill` aes, so you need to include that.

A solution is below:

```
library(tidyr) 
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- gather(df, year, temperature, X1977, X1978, X1979)


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = month, y = temperature, color = year)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = year)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = year, group = year)) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Mean Temperature") +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("1977", "1978","1979"), breaks = c("X1977","X1978","X1979"), values = c("red","green","blue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("X1977" = 1, "X1978" = 1, "X1979" = 2)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("X1977" = 16, "X1978" = 17, "X1979" = 18))
```

[image]

Note how the scales are used. The [ggplot2 documentation site](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/index.html) has fantastic examples.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my data. sorry, the codes you built did not work on my data structure. May I request you for an update on your codes to suit my data set. Many thanks.

Comment: It's very easy to update the code to fit your variables.  Be sure to try to do it yourself prior to asking for help.  Updated code is above